# Use a switch as page transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I use a switch or other methods to transition a page, other than using scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the transition style or do use a switch statement or both?
And by scroll do you mean cover vertical?

to change the transition style go:
.m

```
#import "nextpage.h"
@implementation myproject

-(IBAction)transition:(id)sender {
nextpage *first = [[nextpage alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
first.modaltransitionstyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
}
```

You can replace the

```
UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
```

with

```
UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl
```

and

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical //default transition style
```

and

```
UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
```

If you want a switch statement switching between transitions it takes a bit more effort...
in this case, each button will have a different tag (0, 1, 2, 3) and they are all connected to one action in IB. This is simply because the switch statement won't let you make variables inside it.
.h

```
#import "myfile"
@interface myproject UIViewController {
myfile *first;
}
-(IBAction)myaction:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
#import "myfile"
@implementation myproject 
-(IBAction)myaction:(id)sender {
switch ([sender tag])
case 0:
first = [[myfile alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
break;
case 1:
first = [[myfile alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
break;
case 2:
first = [[myfile alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
break;
case 0:
first = [[myfile alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
break;
default:
break;

}
```

switch statement only (please don't call me sir, I am younger than you think!))
    .m
    -(IBAction)myaction:(id)sender {
    switch ([sender tag])
    case 1:
    //what you want done
    break;
    case 2;
    //what you want done when the sender tag's tag is two
    break;
    //and so on...
    default:
    break;
    }

an IBAction is simply an action that appears in the actions section in Interface Builder (IB= Interface Builder)
the IBAction is used as an action that can be edited in the .m file to do virtually anything.
If this is not the answer you wanted please make a comment on this answer.

Comment: sir may i ask if i need to use switch method only

Comment: sorry i should ask accurately . My work has 8 page , each page is almost the same materials a background , alpha bar , frame , image .........  and how could i not use the scroll to change page , instead using the switch method so that when i each time click a certain area of the bar , so that the page will transit to another page , so sorry and my question is how to use the switch thank you iPhonemaniac for your precious time

Comment: u are very powerful in objective c programming , really need ur help as i am very junior

Comment: indeed i want to ask clearly what is mean and how to use the IBaction

Comment: also iPhonemaniac i have to ask one more question .i have a question on my unanswered question about the addSubview problem really don't know how to tackle it as many  people say the array has problem on it, really don't know why the subview could not be shown and the source code is in that question thank you

Comment: also iphonemaniac really sorry to disturb you much but may i ask how can i check the page index as my teacher only teach me a method in using scroll - use the p_0.x / [scroll frame].size.width to get the present page index , so if i cannot use the scroll method , how can i get the touch index and according to that index to change to the desired page

Comment: or, so when lots of buttons are linked to one action and you want each one to do only one certain thing? because that is where [sender tag] comes in.

Comment: I'll try to answer your other question for now

Comment: Dear iphonemaniac i cannot use the IBaction method as i cannot use the interface builder to build the apps . how can i only use programming method to do the apps ?  (1) what method to use to tackle the problem of getting the page index i want (2) i really stuck by the problem in the addSubview problem of my previous question (3)how can i transit whole of the page with all the image , button content bar to other page with almost the same content

Comment: Why don't you use IB? you can use IBAction even if you are not using IB.

Comment: iphone maniac how can i add you as i really want to be friend with u as u are very professional

Comment: professional? I am not!:) I don't even have a good reputation :( I Honestly don't think i know most of the stuff you are doing!:)

Comment: because my teacher say using IB is not good , the coordinate may change

Comment: really sorry it is really fixed to use programming only

Comment: I will put in an answer how to use IBAction without ib if you like. I'll just do it anyway.

Comment: sorry^^ may u plz check it to see my source code don't know why the subview cannot be shown

Comment: really need ur help to tackle the problem of the subview not shown

Comment: OK found out what's the problem. When you select make a new project in xcode, when it asks for your projects name, below, there are two tick boxes. Untick them and copy and paste all your code in there. Storyboard must not support programmed subviews.

Comment: Is your program for the iphone?

Comment: even with xib it failed again.

Comment: how to implement / modify the program now?

Comment: i now cannot ask question don't know why how can i ask question again

Comment: how bout you ask something like "Objective-C problem, subviews not showing?" as I do not have time to look through all your code. Oh, and  I really think you know more than me because I dont't get some of your code:) I'm a beginner too!

Comment: Is the site not letting you ask any new questions anymore?

Comment: do u have ym yahoo instant messenger

Comment: no, and if you get 8 downvotes on the same question you kinda have to make a new account...

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
@interface myproject : UIViewController {
UIButton *button;
UILabel *label;
}
-(IBAction)action:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
@implementation myproject
-(IBAction)action:(id)sender {
label.text = @"changed";
}
-(void)viewDidLoad {
label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake (x position, y position, width, height);
button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake (x position, y position, width, height);
[button setTitle:@"press" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
button = [buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addsubView:button];
[self.view addSubView:label];
label.text = @"not changed";
}
```